# Is there a way to pull multiple Hamlet and Cassius files into a webpage using scaffolds?

Tags: yesod

I'm trying to use [Atomic Design](https://bradfrost.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/) with Yesod Scaffolds. From what I can tell, I should be able to do it by making widgets, or using interpolation. However; I can't really seem to find much documentation regarding this, and the book on yesodweb isn't really providing much in the way of insight.

If you're unaware of Atomic Design, I've linked it above for you to check out. Essentially I'm wanting to create separate Hamlet and Cassius files, then pull them altogether and render the website.

Answer (score 0):

The `widgetFile` function provided with the Yesod scaffold will automatically join Hamlet, Cassius, Lucius, and Julius files together.

You can see plenty of examples of this here: https://github.com/search?q=widgetFile+language%3Ahaskell&type=Code